# Prepopulate Lightning input field with SEARCH QUERY rather than a record ID

Tags: lightning-aura-components

Suppose I have the following code on Aura

```
<lightning:recordEditForm objectApiName="Opportunity" density="comfy" onload="{! c.onLoad }">

    <lightning:inputField fieldName="Term__c" aura:id="term__c" />
    <lightning:inputField fieldName="StageName" value="Confirmed Interest" />

</lightning:recordEditForm>
```

I would like to prepopulate Term__c (a lookup field) with a search query such as March 2024 rather than use the record ID for the March 2024 record.

Is this possible? Something not too hacky?

I would like to continue using the standard `lightning:recordEditForm`.

--EDIT--

Investigating further, I see that the input element changes quite a bit once you start typing a query onto the lookup component:

FROM:

```
<input 
    lightning-basecombobox_basecombobox="" 
    class="slds-combobox__input slds-input" 
    id="combobox-input-17" 
    type="text" 
    role="combobox" 
    aria-expanded="false" 
    aria-haspopup="listbox" 
    autocomplete="off" 
    data-value="" 
    placeholder="Search Terms..." 
    maxlength="255" 
    aria-autocomplete="list" 
    aria-owns="dropdown-element-17"
    aria-controls="dropdown-element-17" 
    data-position-id="lgcp-1000025" 
    aria-describedby="help-message-14"
>
```

TO:

```
<input 
    lightning-basecombobox_basecombobox="" 
    class="slds-combobox__input slds-input slds-combobox__input-value" <-- changed
    id="combobox-input-17" 
    type="text" 
    role="combobox" 
    aria-expanded="true" <-- changed
    aria-haspopup="listbox" 
    autocomplete="off" 
    data-value="march" <-- new attribute
    placeholder="Search Terms..." 
    maxlength="255" 
    aria-autocomplete="list" 
    aria-owns="dropdown-element-17" 
    aria-controls="dropdown-element-17" 
    data-position-id="lgcp-1000037" <-- changed
    aria-describedby="help-message-14"
    aria-activeDescendant="combobox-input-17-0-17" <-- new attribute
>
```

Any ideas on how to best approach a solution for this?

Answer (score 1):

Term__c is a date field or is it an object?

If it is a date field then you can use DOM Manipulation like -

> **HTML -**
>
> ```
> <lightning:inputField fieldName="Term__c" aura:id="term" class="term"/>
> ```
>
> **Controller -**
>
> ```
> let input = cmp.find("term");
> // OR you can use below statement
> document.querySelector('#term').value = desiredValue;
> ```

**I would suggest you to google about DOM manipulation in aura if you want to know more about it.**

Comment: Thank you I will Google about that. It’s a lookup field (updated the question) so your answer isn’t unfortunately what I need.

Comment: I looked at modifying DOM on aura, and as I see it is mostly about component lifecycles and making sure components are loaded before you try modying them. I don't see how that is relevant to my situation given that I'm calling my `c.onload` function with the `onload` event attribute of the `lightning:recordEditForm` component, which means all important DOM elements are rendered and loaded upon any modification attempts.